# Write and Read method stop my execution - pipes c++

Tags: c++, stdout, stdin

I'm just trying to make a "Tree" where I've a ctrsis and (for now) n "Children" connected to the ctrsis by pipes; But something happen when I try to pass data through pipes from childen to parent and parent to children using stdin and stdout, specificly when I use write() cpp function.

```
//ctrsis.cpp

int
main(void) {
  vector<WriteIn> TubesReference; 
  WriteIn mainTube;
  TubesReference.push_back(mainTube);
  const char* file = "ctrsis.cfg";
  int levelOneProcesses = 0;
  string line;
  ifstream configFile(file);
  if(configFile.is_open()){
    while ( getline (configFile,line) ){
      WriteIn structure = createTube(line);
      TubesReference.push_back(structure);
      levelOneProcesses++;  
    }
  }else{
    cout << "Unable to open file" << endl; 
  } 
  configFile.close();

  if ((TubesReference[0].in = open("ctrsis.cfg", O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
    std::cerr << "Error open file" << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  TubesReference[0].out = TubesReference[1].pipeOut[1];
  for (int i = 1; i < levelOneProcesses; ++i){
    TubesReference[i].in = TubesReference[i].pipeIn[0];
    if(i != TubesReference.size()-1){
      TubesReference[i].out = TubesReference[i+1].pipeOut[1];
    }else{
      TubesReference[TubesReference.size()-1].out = 1;
    }

  }

  pthread_t levelOneThreads[levelOneProcesses];  
  for(int i = 0; i < levelOneProcesses; ++i){
    vector<string> vec;
    istringstream iss(TubesReference[i+1].line);
    copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss),
    istream_iterator<string>(),
    back_inserter(vec));
    string file = "FICHEROCFG=" + vec[4];
    string folder = "DIRDETRABAJO=" + vec[3];
    char* formatFile = new char[file.length()+1]; 
    memcpy(formatFile, file.c_str(), file.length()+1);
    char* formatFolder= new char[folder.length()+1]; 
    memcpy(formatFolder, folder.c_str(), folder.length()+1);
    putenv(formatFile);
    putenv(formatFolder);
    cout << "CTRSIS: CREATE THREAD " << i << endl;
    int ret =  pthread_create(&levelOneThreads[i],NULL, readWriteThread, &TubesReference[i]);
    if(ret != 0) {
      cerr << "Error: pthread_create() failed\n" << endl;
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }else{
       cout << "CTRSIS: JOIN THREAD " << i << endl;
       pthread_join(levelOneThreads[i], NULL);
    }
  }
  //system( "./ctreval" );
  return 0;
}

void* readWriteThread(void *arg) {
  sleep(3);
  WriteIn *dataInOut = (struct WriteIn *) arg;
  cout << "CTRSIS: METHOD" << endl;
  char c;
  while (read(dataInOut->in, &c, 1) > 0) {
    write(dataInOut->out, &c, 1);
  }
  close(dataInOut->in);
  close(dataInOut->out);
  return NULL; 
}
```

This is the evaluator

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

int
main(void) {
 int c;

 while ((c = std::cin.get()) != EOF) {
    c = ::toupper(c);
    std::cout << (char) c;
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Stop as in blocks forever or stop as in program crashes?

Comment: Question needs some work. What's a ctrsis? What's a WriteIn? Why are there 2 main functions? What's the evaluator for? What is "something happen"? What are you trying to do? What's happening instead? What do you want help with?

Comment: Ctrsis is to read a file, and depending of the number of lines in the files I have to create that number of children proccesses (exp: 2 lines, 2 children proccesses), children proccess execute evaluator with different info in the standard input, that input is the output of ctrsis (here is where pipes come) . Each evaluator thread proccess the corresponding input and sends the new data using another pipe to ctrsis again.